# ContextErrorException Notice: Undefined variable - but it did work before

Tags: symfony

```
public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {
        $contact = new Contact();
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $name = $form['name']->getData();
            $email = $form['email']->getData();
            $subject = $form['subject']->getData();
            $message = $form['message']->getData();

            $contact->setName($name);
            $contact->setEmail($email);
            $contact->setSubject($subject);
            $contact->setMessage($message);
        }

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()

            ->setSubject($subject) // here the error
            ->setFrom('jardisindustrie@gmail.com')
            ->setTo($email)
            ->setBody($this->renderView('sendmail.html.twig', array(
                'name' => $name,
                'message' => $message,
                'email' => $email,
                'subject' => $subject)), 'text/html');
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

        return $this->render('SDCoreBundle::contact.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }
```

I don't know why but it did work good and this afternoon I try again and I have the error message...

I want to make a contact form with swiftmailer, normally I do like that but here i don't know why there is a trouble.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the complete error message. But from the first look, the code that creates and sends a message should be inside the `if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` block, otherwise it will try to send a message when the form is not submited but only being displayed.

Comment: arf... stupid mistake :p thanks for your help Goran it works again.